# Windows 7- Constant Crashing and BSODs

Tags: windows-7, crash, bsod

I re-installed Windows 7 on my machine and I keep getting BSODs after a fresh install.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Dump:

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 100713-39359-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 07/10/2013 23:32:12
Bug Check String  : IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000000a
Parameter 1       : fffffa4f`ffffffe0
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000002
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000001
Parameter 4       : fffff800`0284e151
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+80640
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+80640
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\100713-39359-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 290,584
Dump File Time    : 07/10/2013 23:33:47
==================================================
```

I have re-installed Windows 7 Unlike for like 3 times and tried burning different CDs.

Comment: Although the report states the Kernel failing, I often had on Vista `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` errors due to graphics problems.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard graphics problems as in what ?

Comment: Mainly I had a very glitchy graphics board that decided to crash Vista whenever it wanted. But that error could be from other reasons, I just stated my experience with that.

Comment: upload all dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump\ o that we can look at them with a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

That dump file gives the exact driver that is failing.  Wikipedia says the following about ntoskrnl.exe: "ntoskrnl.exe (Short for Windows NT Operating System Kernel, and ntkrnlpa.exe on systems with Physical Address Extension support) is the kernel image for the family of Microsoft Windows NT operating systems. It provides the kernel and executive layers of the Windows NT kernel space, and is responsible for various system services such as hardware virtualization, process and memory management, etc., thus making it a fundamental part of the system. It contains the cache manager, the executive, the kernel, the security reference monitor, the memory manager, and the scheduler, among other things."

1. Make sure your RAM is good (run memtest)
2. Try booting in Safe Mode, does that work?
3. Disable virtualization in your BIOS
4. Revert your BIOS back to factory defaults
5. Try a different HDD, maybe your disk is bad?
6. Try Linux, can you install and run linux?

If all the above fails, buy a new motherboard.

[Quote Source on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntoskrnl)

Answer (score 1):

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL is almost always related to a hardware problem, but that includes drivers.  Unfortunately, it's not a definitive problem.  It can be caused by memory, motherboard problems, disk failure, graphics cards, etc.  Start with:

- Download whocrashed, which may give a clearer hint of the issue
  http://www.resplendence.com/download/whocrashedSetup.exe
- Run SFC/SCANNOW to ensure that system file versions are correct
- Run Memtest to check RAM
- Swap out RAM in case the failures are not consistent enough for Memtest to catch
- Check the disk drive
- Reseat cards in the system
- Remove unneeded cards & devices for now
- Back-rev the graphics driver
- Monitor system temps

Note that if you recently changed some hardware or updated a driver, that's probably it.  And if it always happens when you're busy gaming, it's probably the video card or the driver, thus the suggestion to back-rev the driver.